# Find value from an object and array of keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of keys `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and nested object `{ a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } }`
How can get a value of nested object `'58'`?
I tried something like this, but I've got only value from one 'level'

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const b = { a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } }
const getValue = (a,b) => { return Object.values(b).find(key => a[key] === b[key]) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.reduce()` method can help.

Call `.reduce()` on the array and pass object `b` as the initial value to the `.reduce()` method. Callback function of the `.reduce()` method should just return the result of `acc[curr]`.

During the first call, `acc` will be the object `b` and `curr` will be the first element in the array, i.e. `'a'`. So the first call to callback function will return `b['a']`, i.e. `{ b: { c: { d: '58' } } }`.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const b = { a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } };

const result = a.reduce((acc, curr) => acc[curr], b);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a naturally recursive operation, so this is a perfect use case for a recursive function:

```js
const getValue = (Target, [k, ...Kr]) => 
  Kr.length > 0 
    ? getValue(Target[k], Kr)
    : Target[k];

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } }

console.log(getValue(obj, keys));
```

But you could also use array reducers:

```js
const getValue = (obj, keys) => 
  keys.reduce((target, key) => target[key] ,obj);

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } }

console.log(getValue(obj, keys));
```

Or just a regular for loop:

```js
const getValue = (obj, keys) => {
  let target = obj;
  for (let k of keys) {
    target = target[k];
  }
  return target;
}

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: '58' } } } }

console.log(getValue(obj, keys));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
b[a[0]][a[1]][a[2]][a[3]]
```

it will output `58`

I'm not sure if your array `a` fixed size?

if the size is dynamic

Try

```js
function getValue(a, b) {
    let output = b;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        output = output[a[i]];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I need more elegant decision